# Async function in componentDidMount doesn't work on second mount react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I've got a list of flags that when clicked on change the language of my app and the current language flag gets bigger.

For the current language, I'm using a different API that requires me to do an async process. It works when I run the app for the first time, but when I try to change it, the language changes, but the flag stays the same.

```
export default class FlagImage extends Component {
  state = {};
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getFlag();
    console.log("mounted"); //hundreds of logs
  }
  getFlag = async (name = this.props.name) => {
    const url = `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${name}`;
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const json = await res.json();
    const flagURL = json.flag;
    this.setState({ flagURL });
  };

  render() {
    const { name, big } = this.props;

    return name ? (
      big ? (
        <img alt={`Flag ${name}`} src={this.state.flagURL} width="87px" height="58px" />
      ) : (
        <img alt={`Flag ${name}`} src={`https://www.countryflags.io/${name}/flat/32.png`} />
      )
    ) : (
      <div />
    );
  }
}
```

in my jsx:

```
        <div //this div works like a button
          className={styles["flag2"]}
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({ open: !this.state.open });
          }}>
          <FlagImage name={this.getCountryCode()} big={true} />
        </div>
```

Comment: Does the `name` property changes because you're setting it using a function `this.getCountryCode()` not a state property ? What does this function return ?

Comment: the function returns a countryCode. That means "us", "es", etc...
The countryCode (name) changes everytime the user changes the language.

Comment: Explain what you mean by "second mount"? It seems like you're referring to a subsequent render and not a newly mounted component instance. If that's the case, then the code is working as expected, but you need to use a different lifecycle method

Comment: Yes, I meant a subsequent render, just didn't know how else I would call it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. Just call it a re-render in that case. A re-mount is when a component instance is destroyed and a new one is created in its place. The basic implications being: a re-render maintains state, a re-mount loses its state. In addition, a re-mount begins a new lifecycle so it will call the constructor, componentDidMount, etc. A re-render will just continue the lifecycle, so `componentDidUpdate`, etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
export default class FlagImage extends Component {
  state = {};
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getFlag();
    console.log("mounted"); //hundreds of logs
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot){
     if (this.props.name !== prevProps.name || this.props.big !== prevProps.big) {
            this.getFlag();
     }
  }

  getFlag = async (name = this.props.name) => {
    const url = `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${name}`;
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const json = await res.json();
    const flagURL = json.flag;
    this.setState({ flagURL });
  };

  render() {
    const { name, big } = this.props;

    return name ? (
      big ? (
        <img alt={`Flag ${name}`} src={this.state.flagURL} width="87px" height="58px" />
      ) : (
        <img alt={`Flag ${name}`} src={`https://www.countryflags.io/${name}/flat/32.png`} />
      )
    ) : (
      <div />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This works too. :) Either `componentDidReceiveProps` or `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: This is a correct answer, but for clarity and completeness, I'd add only the relevant pieces of code and explain what the your code does to fix the problem. In your case, just explain that the `componentDidUpdate` should replace the `componentDidMount` and what the difference is between the two

Comment: componentDidMount just call once time when your component created but componentDidUpdate can be call every time you change this component properties out side of component where you call it. like this : <FlagImage name={this.getCountryCode()} big={true} />. for this code you can remove componentDidMount